# How to change the prompt of lldb?

Tags: debugging, lldb

What is the lldb equivalent of gdb [`set prompt`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Prompt.html)?

I'd like to change the prompt (`(lldb)` by default) of lldb.

Pseudo behavior:

```
$ lldb
(lldb) set prompt "> "
Prompt is set to '> '.
> version
lldb-1205.0.27.3
Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)
```

Edit:
I found `settings set prompt <prompt>` works, but I cannot include a newline in `<prompt>` while `set prompt \n>` works as expected in gdb. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Adding newlines in the prompt string works in the current TOT llvm.org lldb, and in the lldb that ships with Xcode 13.4.1:

```
$ lldb
(lldb) set set prompt "\n> "

> version
lldb-1316.0.9.46
Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)

> target list
No targets.

>
```

Comment: I don't remember exactly when this support was added, however.